# string index out of range list iteration

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am fairly new to python, I am not sure on how to fix a index string out of range. it happens right after the while loop when I want to send mylist[i][0] to formatting function.  Any pointer on my code in general would be awesome!

```
    def formatting(str1):

if str1 == '?':
    return True
else:
    return False

while(i <= len(mylist)):
    val = formatting(mylist[i][0])
    if val == True:
        str1 = mylist[i]
        str2 = mylist[i+1]
        i = i + 2
        format_set(str1, str2)
    else:
        if format == True:
            if (margin + count + len(mylist[i])) <= width:
                if (i == (len(mylist)-1)):
                    list2.append(mylist[i])
                    print(" " * margin + " ".join(list2))   
                    break
            list2.append(mylist[i])
            count += len(mylist[i])
            i += 1                          
        else:
            print(" " * margin + " ".join(list2))
            list2 = []
            count = 0
    else:
        temp_margin = margin
        temp_width = width
        width = 60
        margin = 0
        if (margin + count + len(mylist[i])) <= width:
            if (i == (len(mylist)-1)):
                list2.append(mylist[i])
                print(" " * margin + " ".join(list2))
                margin = temp_margin
                width = temp_width
                break
            list2.append(mylist[i])
            count += len(mylist[i])
            i += 1                          
        else:
            print(" " * margin + " ".join(list2))
            list2 = []
            count = 0
```

Comment: Use 4 spaces to introduce correct indentation in your code. TAB doesn't work for this here.

Answer (score 1):

In the last iteration of the `while` loop, `i` is referring to the last value. Hence,

```
str2 = mylist[i+1]
```

is trying to reference a string *outside* the allowed range and you get an error.

EDIT: Also, as Wcrousse mentioned, the `while (i <= len(...))` should be changed to `i < len(...)` because indexes go from 0 - (length-1).

Comment: I get the error on the line val = formatting(mylist[i][0]), it doesn't get a chance to make it to the str2 = mylist[i+1]

Comment: Post your definition of `formatting()`. It is likely making the same mistake within.

Comment: Wcrousse's answer was the main reason for your issue. Using `i <= len(mylist)` would push the last iteration of `i` outside the range.

Comment: with changing it to i < len(mylist) I still get the error.  for the str2 = mylist[i+1] if it makes it to that point there is for sure a i+1

Answer (score 1):

change

```
i <= len(mylist)
```

to

```
i < len(mylist)
```

Comment: you'll still have to deal with the mylist[i+1] that Abhi mentioned.